# how to make a function but select different div (Like php class)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm newbie in Jquery, how to make a function but select different div (Like php class)?

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#box-1").hover(function(){
    $("#mebox-1").removeClass("hide");
    $("#circle-1").addClass("hide");      
  });
  $("#box-1").mouseleave(function(){
    $("#mebox-1").addClass("hide");
    $("#circle-1").removeClass("hide");
  });
});
```

And I want to use this function for box-xxx. This is my HTML cod sample:

```
<div id="box-1" class="box">
   <div id="circle-1" class="circle"></div>
   <div id="mebox-1" class="hide circle-bg">
      test
   </div>
</div>
<div id="box-2" class="box">
   <div id="circle-2" class="circle"></div>
   <div id="mebox-2" class="hide circle-bg">
      test
   </div>
</div>
<div id="box-3" class="box">
   <div id="circle-3" class="circle"></div>
   <div id="mebox-3" class="hide circle-bg">
      test
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: like box-1 use the id of your other div

Comment: wrap the code in a function and use `$("#box-" + boxno)` or `$(boxIDForbox-xx)`

Comment: No don't do that, show your html, we'll direct you to the optimized way..

Comment: I know can use functions one by one but I'm sure its not a good way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use that common classes attached with those elements, And most importantly use the `this` reference so that we can target the elements inside the element over which we are moving.

```
$(".box").hover(function(){
   $(".circle-bg",this).removeClass("hide");
   $(".circle",this).addClass("hide");      
},function(){
   $(".circle-bg",this).addClass("hide");
   $(".circle",this).removeClass("hide");  
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jA2Qc/1/)

Answer (score 2):

As you have already defined common classes. You should use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to get the descendants.

Use

```
$(".box").hover(function(){
   $(this).find(".circle-bg").removeClass("hide");
   $(this).(".circle").addClass("hide");      
},function(){
   $(this).find(".circle-bg").addClass("hide");
   $(this).find(".circle").removeClass("hide");  
});
```

Also I have passed the `mouseleave` event handler as second argument to `.hover()` function.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this:

```
var n="";
$('[id^="box-"]').hover(function(){
   n = this.id.split('-')[1];
   $("#mebox-"+n).removeClass("hide");
   $("#circle-"+n).addClass("hide");      
},function(){
   $("#mebox-"+n).addClass("hide");
   $("#circle-"+n).removeClass("hide");
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jA2Qc/2/)

Comment: What do you mean not worked? wait i will post a fiddle with this code.